# how to Use Covering Indexes to Improve Query Performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any performance issue with a filtered nonclustered index in this scenario?

I have a Heap table with 10 columns:

```
Create table Test()
{
    Field1 INT,
    Field2 INT,
    Field3 UNIQUEIDENTIFER,
    Field4 DATETIME,
    Field5 DATETIME,
    Field6 DATETIME,
    Field7 INT,
    Field8 INT,
    Field9 INT,
    Field10 INT 
}
```

End user can get report from this table with this query statement :

```
select Field1, Field2 
from Test 
Where Field4 between @Date1 And @Date2
```

and table `Test` is a large table with millions of rows.

I want to create a filtered nonclusterd index on the table like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Field4 
ON Test (Field4)
WHERE Field4 <= @FirstDateOfYear AND Field4 >= @LastDateOfYear
```

`@Date1` And `@Date2` parameter can be any date in different year or same year but usually these two parameters are in the current year.

`@firstDateOfYear` and `@LastDateOfYear` parameter are fixed that refer to first and last date of current year.

Is there any performance issue and in your opinion will SQL Server use my index at any time ?

Assume that I can not change this table structure such as create a clustered index on table `Test` and things like this

Comment: First, I would make a covering index, including field1 and field2 in the filtered index definition.  Otherwise, you might be doing a key lookup on those two columns.  

Secondly, I would verify that the execution plan is identical to using BETWEEN rather than ANDing two dates.

Comment: What kind of indexes are you suggesting?

Comment: so how is your performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, disregard my previous comment.  You cannot use between on a filtered index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Field4 
ON Test (Field4)
INCLUDE ([Field1], [Field2])
WHERE Field4 <= @FirstDateOfYear AND Field4 >= @LastDateOfYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Create `Field11 INT` in your table
2. Fill `Field11 = MillisecondsOf(Field4)`
3. Seek by table like this

   ```
   select Field1, Field2 
   from Test 
   where Field11 <= MillisecondsOf(@Date1) 
     and Field11 >= MillisecondsOf(@Date2)
   ```

Comment: i can not Change This Table Structure Was in My Note,and i cant Change Table Structure.